# Why do some applications lock files and others don't?

Tags: c#, excel

In my datalogging application I write to a temporary file of the form ... AppData\Local\Temp\euaxgd5z.csv

This opens by default in Excel.

```
Process.Start(TempFileLocationBox.Text.ToString());
```

The next time the timer tries to write more data to this file, an exception is thrown. However if I open it with TextPad

```
Process.Start("textpad.exe", TempFileLocationBox.Text.ToString());
```

it can write to the file quite happily and TextPad will ask if I want to reload it. How can I get Excel to behave as nicely as TextPad?

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: Your best bet would be to ask Microsoft to change the way Excel opens the file (share/lock mode comes to mind). I would advise you don't hold your breath, though. There may be legitimate reasons for Excel to do that.

Comment: System.IO.IOException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024864
  Message=The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Temp\euaxgd5z.csv' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Really? I'm new to .NET and assumed everything was possible!

Comment: Probably down to how Excel auto-saves. If it doesn't lock the file the autosave could overwrite somebody elses work.

Comment: Try opening it with a readonly file sharing mode.

Comment: It is because Excel has a 1-800 support phone number.  And the people that answer it don't have fantastic solutions for "my colleague overwrote the spreadsheet while I was editing it and when I saved mine, his changes were lost.  I need those changes".

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't even try to 'communicate' to excel the fact that you want the file reloaded.  I would just write a new file and open a new copy of excel, after closing the old copy if possible.

That way you won't need to worry if the user is using open office instead, for example.